# is it possible to visualize pipeline runs of over 30 days?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a list of azure pipelines and I want to see the executions of 30+ days, is it possible? i think I can only see the ones within 30 days. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I've already saw how haha thank you, it is in:

Settings -> Days to keep runs of, and apparently you can set it as high as 2 years.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark it as an answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution and we could archive this thread, thanks